# how to convert assembler vector to data frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I just used `VectorAssembler` to normalize my features for a ML application.

```scala
def kmeansClustering ( k : Int ) : sql.DataFrame  = { 
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
        .setInputCols(this.listeOfName())
        .setOutputCol("features")
    val intermediaireDF = assembler
        .transform(this.filterNumeric())
        .select("features")
    val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(k).setSeed(1L)
    val model = kmeans.fit(intermediaireDF)
    val predictions = model.transform(intermediaireDF)
    return(predictions)
  }
```

as a result I got a 2 vectors dataframe:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|            features|prediction|
+--------------------+----------+
|[-27.482279,153.0...|         0|
|[-27.47059,153.03...|         2|
|[-27.474531,153.0...|         3| 
.................................
```

So I want to perform something like avg and std by group for each column but the features are assembled and I can't do manipulation on them.

I've tried to use `org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorDisassembler`, but it did not work.

```
 val disassembler = new VectorDisassembler().setInputCol("vectorCol")
 disassembler.transform(df).show()
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: are you using https://github.com/jamesbconner/VectorDisassembler ? and are you getting any errors, if so please update with the issues/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need to remove the original columns to perform your clustering.

```scala
// creating sample data
val df = spark.range(10).select('id as "a", 'id %3 as "b")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("a", "b")).setOutputCol("features")

// Here I delete the select so as to keep all the columns
val intermediaireDF = assembler.transform(this.filterNumeric())

// I specify explicitely what the feature column is
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK( 2 ).setSeed(1L).setFeaturesCol("features")

// And the rest remains unchanged
val model = kmeans.fit(intermediaireDF)
val predictions = model.transform(intermediaireDF)

predictions.show(6)
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  a|  b|  features|prediction|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  1|  0| [1.0,0.0]|         1|
|  2|  1| [2.0,1.0]|         1|
|  3|  2| [3.0,2.0]|         1|
|  4|  0| [4.0,0.0]|         1|
|  5|  1| [5.0,1.0]|         0|
|  6|  2| [6.0,2.0]|         0|
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

And from there, you can compute what you need.